# How advisable is migrating to spring framework?

Tags: java, apache-flex, spring

Currently we have a framework(a customized MVC pattern in flex and command pattern in java) which works well with our use case. we are thinking about migration of our server to spring framework. How advisable it is?. our java framework is also loosely coupled.But I see spring more loosely coupled with some concepts Dependency injection and inversion of control( which i still need to get some idea).Basically in what kind of use-case people use spring.How efficient it is?.if its advisable also please let me know where to start with.

Comment: What do you mean by "advisable"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a framework like Spring or Guice helps you keep your applications organized and loosely coupled over time. A dependency injection framework essentially extracts object construction away from an application, allowing the application to focus on what it needs to do instead of any architectural concerns.

Another upfront advantage of using dependency injection is that your application no longer worries about object construction, thus allowing you to build mock objects to test each portion of you application independently.

I highly suggest reading Dhanji Prasanna's book [Dependency Injection](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193398855X).

Comment: I prefer [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) because it has completely type-safe configuration (no XML) and was written with Java 5 (specifically generics) in mind. The API is also much cleaner than Spring, and I would argue more powerful.

Answer (score 1):

One benefit of moving to spring is that new developers you bring on will be more likely to know that tool, and may come up to speed faster.

That being said, rewriting an app needs to require a lot of justification.  Is your current architecture failing you for any reason?

Comment: The OP is using Flex, not HTML, so SpringMVC doesn't make sense here. The question is about Spring as a dependency injection container.